# How to set text views and toggle buttons side by side like a list

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginer in android ,i have 5 toggle buttons in my app,and also have 5 text views for each button ,how can i set the toggle buttons and text views one by one like  a list.I have this code to set a single text view and a toggle button  horizontally.I want to set more buttons with its text views one by one vertically.Can anybody help me for this issue,and i'm sorry for my poor language.

`

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="12:00 AM"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button Text" />
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stack layouts within one an another. Here is how  you can do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="12:00 AM"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Text" />

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="12:00 AM"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Text" />

    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="12:00 AM"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Text" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How can i add scroll view for all these text views and buttons??? It shows error when i set scroll view for this layout

Comment: Actualy i want set the scroll view for the same code above,I want to add more buttons and text views ,so i think a scroll view is neccesary

Comment: ,How can i set the scroll view for the text views and buttons together.Actually i have 24 buttons and 24 text views for each time.Hope u understood